# How can I reference a cell's value in PowerQuery Within the Table.Combine Function

Tags: excel, powerquery

Hi I'm really new to this. I saw the post [on how to reference a cell value][1].

However, I would like to know how to use this function when combining tables in PowerQuery.

What I had:
= Table.Combine({#"Statement 1", #"Statement 2"})

What I want:

= Table.Combine(GetValue("SourceFile"))

Hope I didn't ask this to confusing.

Comment: You want to (a) combine two existing query tables, where you specify the the table names using two variables (b) combine two named tables from excel where you specify the names using two variables (c) combine two external files using the file path you specify using two variables (d) something else.

Comment: The "SourceFile" Is a reference to a cell Value on a excel spreadsheet. That cell contains the names of the query tables that I want to Combine into one Table. So basically I don't want to type #"Statement 1" and rather reference a list of those queries from a cell value. Thenthe Table.Combine Function should see the cell value as a list of queries that it should Combine into one.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the current worksheet: if I have Table1 like this...

[image]

...and Table2 like this...

[image]

...and my names of the query tables are entered into a cell that I named SourceFile in my spreadsheet like this...

[image]

Then I can call this function...

```
(GetValue)=>
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceFile"]}[Content],
  Custom1 = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"Column1", each List.Transform(Text.Split(_,","), each Expression.Evaluate(_,#shared))}),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Custom1, "Column1"),
    Column1 = #"Expanded Column1"[Column1]
in
  Column1
```

...by using...

```
Table.Combine(GetValue("SourceFile"))
```

...to get...

[image]

Comment: This is correct. It worked well!